Why isn't my image showing up in my report?
I have SQL Server 2022 (v16.0) installed on my personal PC. I'm using Report Builder v15.0. I set up reporting services and am able to save a report to my ReportServer database.
In Report Builder, I made a table and made one of the columns hold an image. In the image properties, I set the image source to External and selected the image that I saved to ReportServer. When I run the report, the image doesn't show up. All I see if a white box with a red X.

How do I make the image show up? Also - I should note that I don't want to be saving the images to report server. I want to save them to a specific folder on my desktop because I also have a python project that will be referencing the same folder of images. How do I make this work so that my report references a folder on my desktop for the images?

The images should exists in the path defined in the expression.
If the image expression is defined as C:\test.png, in order to display in the report, it should exist in any computer running the report.
I would suggest using images with HTTP or UNC paths


